# SVG scaling: Parent container maintaining original .svg height in IE9

Tags: svg, image, responsive-design, scaling

```
**CSS**

.testSVG { background: gray; width: 50%; }
.testSVG img { margin: 10px; max-width: 100%; }

**HTML:** 

<div class="testSVG">
    <img src="http://www.html5rocks.com/static/demos/svgmobile_fundamentals/images/HTML5-  logo.svg" alt="html5">
</div>
```

[SVG Scaling example](http://jsfiddle.net/24FNE/)

In Firefox the parent div (in this example .testSVG) scaled both horizontally and vertically with the scaling .svg image.

However in IE9 the parent div scales on horizontally while the .svg is still scaled both horizontally and vertically.

I liked to duplicate what is happening in Firefox in IE as well. Does anyone have any insight?

Thanks,
Z

Comment: you could add javascript to the svg, set up a resize listener and try to handle it yourself

Comment: As a last resort I probably will do that but I'd rather explore the possibilities of a javascript-less way.

Comment: It appears that the parent container still maintains the height of the orignial svg's viewBox height in IE, where FF scales both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and I followed the answer in a similar question:

[SVG in img element proportions not respected in ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777143/svg-in-img-element-proportions-not-respected-in-ie9)

essentially I removed the height and width attributes from the svg tag.

Removing these tags also happened to fix an issue in Safari where extra spacing was getting introduced.