# SVG not rendering in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, svg

I have a .svg logo on my website, http://www.dailydoog.com, and it renders correctly in every browser except for Internet Explorer. Even newer versions of IE (9+) that have built-in SVG support won't render the logo.

I'm using the following markup

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

but it doesn't seem to be having any impact.
Am I just missing something really simple here?

Comment: How do you render it? What content-type returned from server?

Comment: Is converting it to a PNG not a solution? It's pretty plain for an SVG...

Comment: @madhead the svg was rendering correctly in IE, but I was applying a width without a height and therefor it wasn't showing up based on the CSS rules I had applied.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn I wanted to use .svg because my site is responsive and I didn't want the extra overhead from a PNG. Honestly though either could have worked fine.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Navigating directly to the SVG in question works fine.

If you use the F12 Developer Tools to disable CSS on the page, the SVG image renders.

If you remove the `width` property from `#logo-image img`, it renders, or you can add a `height:35px` property instead and the SVG will render.

Perhaps related to this question? [SVG in img element proportions not respected in ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777143/svg-in-img-element-proportions-not-respected-in-ie9)

Comment: you're the man! Thanks so much for your help. I just left the  svg at it's native resolution and now it's working correctly across all browsers.