# Keep ratio of SVG with IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I've SVG with a background image like :

```
<svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" viewBox="0 -505 500 505" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1">

<image xlink:href="style/image/svg/background.jpg" x="0" width="489.72" y="-501.813" height="501.813"/>

<g id="limits">

<path class="limits_1" d='M 435.93263055394345 -85.347777874162432 L 439.53269849462669 -78.780584897426891 438.66214876086451 -74.05024425651645 435.83861350815863 -72.351379868481317 437.4283067958022 -70.182109196687819 435.8171570844774 ... Z'/>

</g>

</svg>
```

I call him in web page :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/css/svg_index.css" media="all"/>

<div id="global">
    <div id = "map">
        <?php
            include( "data/svg/mysvg.svg" );
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I manage style with this CSS :

```
#global {
    width:100%;
    min-height: 555px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 100%;
}

#map{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    float: right;
}

#map > svg {
    width:100%;
    height: 96%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.limits_1 {
    fill: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 1;
}
```

When I want to see the result on many on IE 10 or IE Edge, all it's ok I've this result :

[image]

But when I try the emulation on IE 9 I've this !

[image]

My picture is the same but she's reduce.

I founded this [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777143/svg-in-img-element-proportions-not-respected-in-ie9) on StackOverflow, but in my case, I can't write my svg in imb balise because I've Javascript interaction with it.

Thank you.

Comment: If you provide a playable example, you certainly will have more answers. You can use the StackOverflow snippets or an external tool like jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't found this answer, can you give me the link please ?

Comment: Here is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/30416241/1978945

Comment: It's perfect thank you very much !