# SVG not center in div on IE11

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, svg

I have an SVG inside a div that I am trying to center by using absolute positioning. On IE11 the SVG is off-center though. When I remove the absolute positioning it appears that the starting point of the SVG is different on IE11 and Chrome. On IE11 the SVG is a few pixels further down the page then on Chrome.

I tried using a Flexbox solution instead of absolute positioning, but the same issue persists. Even when using `align-items: center` and `justify-content: center`, the IE11 version was a few pixels lower than the Chrome version.

This leads me to believe it is really not a positioning issue at all, but rather there is some fundamental difference between SVG display or positioning on IE11. I am using a VM to debug on IE11 but it is extremely laggy and pain-staking to develop on.

Is there some fundamental difference between display/positioning of SVG's on IE11? Can someone shed some light on this strange behavior?

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/29zwax4j/)

Also, here is a screenshot of the same code running locally on both Chrome and IE11 side by side:
[image]

EDIT:

It also appears like the SVG is off when I inspect it in IE dev tools:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin meet"` in your svg elenent (see https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute for more info) and remove width and height attributes (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9792254/895007).

Comment: IE11 doesn't much like the removal of width and height usually.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0,-50%);
height: $desiredHeightInPixels;
width: 100%;
```