# Svg elements borders disappear when zooming in IE11

Tags: html, css, svg, internet-explorer-11

I use svg icons that look fine on different browsers, but on IE11 some of the borders of the svg elements, like rect or line, are not visible on certain zoom levels. For example, at 23px width, everything is visible, but on 24px some borders disappear.

This is a normal image:

[image]

This is zoomed in a bit:

[image]

Another zoom level:

[image]

Comment: Assume that probably the best way to not have such issues in IE would be to not use svgs..

Answer (score 1):

To get more consistent scaling across browsers always ensure you specify a `viewBox` but leave off the `width` and `height` attributes on your `svg` element.

source: [SVG in img element proportions not respected in ie9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9777143/svg-in-img-element-proportions-not-respected-in-ie9/9792254#9792254)

A shell command that will remove `width` & `height` attributes from all SVG files in the current directory:

`find ./ -name '*.svg' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "" -e 's/width="[0-9]*\.*\[0-9]*" //' -e 's/height="[0-9]*\.*\[0-9]*" //'`

source: https://gist.github.com/larrybotha/7881691

Comment: It doesn't seem to be an issue as the svg I use doesn't have the width and height, but have a viewBox it's generated by Illustrator.

A simplified version is:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.2.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
  viewBox="0 0 59 83.8" style="enable-background:new 0 0 59 83.8;" xml:space="preserve">
<title>Untitled-2</title>
 <rect x="12.5" y="5.5" class="st0" width="1" height="73.8" fill="orange"/>
</svg>

Comment: Even if I put this simple svg which result should be a 1px line IE once show once hide the line when zooming. The problem is of course not with zooming but with scaling the svg itself on page as on some display it will look allright in IE but on the other it won't have some lines invisible.

Comment: Try removing the `width` and `height` on the `rect`.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but after removing width and height on rect it's not visible as it doesn't have any dimensions.

Comment: @ebsk Try manually setting the width and height in the `style` attribute of the SVG element to see if that resolves the distortion.  Make sure you are using the height and width from the SVG's `viewBox`.  IE doesn't have a way to figure out the height of an SVG based on it's width.